# Not able to open .groovy files in Groovy Editor in GGTS 3.4.0

Tags: groovy

In GGTS 3.4.0, i am not able to open .groovy files using groovy editor. My .project has the following natures added

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.grails.ide.eclipse.core.nature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.groovyNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
</natures>
```

One error which i get on saving any groovy file is:
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'ml-app'.
org/codehaus/jdt/groovy/integration/LanguageSupportFactory

Any help in resolving this error and being able to use groovy editor is appreciated.

Comment: Try to clean the Grail project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloaded GGTS 3.5.1 today. The new version does not have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit this issue after i did some eclipse update yesterday.

i uninstalled JDT Core patch (Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details)

- JDT Core patch with Java 8 Support for Groovy-Eclipse plugin 2.90.xx-201403261719-e43j8

seem to work - i'm able to view/edit groovy files now in Eclipse

whew!